# How to move image to a folder after applying ImageJPEG for compression?

Tags: php, image-uploading, image-compression

I need some help regarding image compression & moving the compressed image to destination folder. i'm using:

```
ImageJPEG(ImageCreateFromString(file_get_contents('source file','target file','90')));
```

How can I upload the compressed file resulting from the above statement?

My Code:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['pic']['name'])){
    $tempFile = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = substr(sha1(rand(000,9999)),0,7).$_FILES['pic']['name'];
    $targetPath = getcwd().'/assets/admin/images/image-gallery/'; 
    ImageJPEG (ImageCreateFromString (file_get_contents ($tempFile,$fileName,90)));
    $CompressedFile = $targetPath.$fileName;
    copy($fileName,$CompressedFile);
```

Help me out with this please....

Comment: Use `copy()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php and after you can delete the one you are copying

Comment: Could you specify how to use copy, the manual says that it requires Source & Target, but ImageJPEG returns a boolean, so what path do i specify as Source?

Comment: I think @Chris answer is better, just pass the path to the function like this `imagejpeg($yourimage, $path);`

Comment: if you use `copy` you need to use it like this `copy(path_of_your_original_image, 'path_where_you_want_to_move');` but as the name says it will copy the original to the path you specify but if you dont want to keep both images you can delete the original image after the function copy `unlink('original_image');`

Comment: i want to save the compressed image, not the original one. Please tell according to my code above, what should i enter as the path of the Compressed image in copy function?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in imagejpeg is the path to the output file, otherwise the image is just dumped to the screen.

[PHP.net imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)